# Navigate to='/' is not working in react router dom 6 route

Tags: node.js, react-router-dom

As we all know react router Dom V6 is using Navigate instead of Redirect. I am using Navigate but I don't know how and where i should use this. {user ?  : }

I am writing this way

<Route path="/login" element={}>
{user ?  : }

Can anyone please tell how should i write this Navigate {user ?  : } in my route which is  <Route path="/login" element={}>